# flacards package: how to disable centering?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, flashcards

I want to create flashcards with the `flacards` package. However, this package automatically centers everything you write on the cards. Is there an easy way to disable that?
I want to write cards that are left aligned, like normal text.

(FYI, I am using the newest TexMaker and MikTex 2.9)

Comment: Note that [`flacards`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/flacards) is a document class, not a package.

Comment: BTW: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a solution.

Add these lines in your preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\cardtextstylef}{\raggedright\itshape}
\renewcommand{\cardtextstyleb}{\raggedright\itshape}
```

Example (taken from `flacards` documentation and modified):

```
\documentclass[frontgrid]{flacards}

\renewcommand{\cardtextstylef}{\raggedright\itshape}
\renewcommand{\cardtextstyleb}{\raggedright\itshape}

\begin{document}
\card{gehen\\schlafen}{to go/to walk\\to sleep}
\card{hell, klar}{bright}
\card{mit\\ohne}{with\\without}
\card{Lernkarte}{flashcard}
\card{Wasser}{water}
\card{Saft}{juice}
\card{Fenster}{window}
\card{Linie}{line}
\card{und\\oder}{and\\or}
\card{Regen}{rain}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]